# Pipe Date Angular "Unable to convert "Timestamp"

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use a pipe in angular, specifically the following: `{{fechaCreacion | date: 'medium'}}` and I get the following error: `Unable to convert Timestamp (seconds = 1528157765, nanoseconds = 878000000)" into a date 'for pipe' DatePipe'`

This is my registration in Firestore: 
[image]

When I just leave `{{ fechaCreacion }}` it shows me the following:

[image]

How can I solve that?

I'm using:

Angular 6

"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.10"

"firebase": "^5.0.4",

component.ts

```
  aviso: any = {};
  id;
  titulo;
  descripcion;
  fechaCreacion;
  categoria;

  constructor( private fs: FirebaseService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.fs.getAvisoObject(this.id).valueChanges().forEach(aviso => {
      this.titulo= aviso.titulo,
      this.descripcion = aviso.descripcion,
      this.fechaCreacion = aviso.fechaCreacion,
      this.categoria = aviso.categoria
    });
  }
```

component.html

```
<mat-card class="px-3 px-md-5 py-3 py-md-4 rounded">
    <div class="row no-gutters small pb-2 mb-3 d-flex justify-content-between border-bottom text-muted">
      <div>
        <span>{{ categoria }}</span>
      </div> 
      <div>
        <span>{{ fechaCreacion | date : 'medium' }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h2 class="font-weight-bold">{{ titulo }}</h2>
    <h5 class="font-weight-light">{{ descripcion }}</h5>
  </mat-card>
```

service.ts

```
getAvisoObject(id: string) {
this.avisoObject = this.afs.doc('avisos/' + id);
return this.avisoObject;
}
```

Comment: It should be timestamp as number only. No wonder `Timestamp (seconds = 1528157765, nanoseconds = 878000000)` cannot be converted

Comment: Edit your question to show the code that generates the part of the page that's incorrect.  Right now we are just guessing where that comes from.

Comment: You're right, @DougStevenson I already edited it. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When dealing with timestamp type data in Firestore (that's your `fechaCreacion` field in the document shown), the Firestore client libraries will give you a [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp.html) type object in response to queries.  You need to use this Timestamp to format a date for display in the browser.

Timestamp represents times with nanosecond precision, which involves two integers, which you are seeing on screen.  If you want a JavaScript Date object instead, you could use the [toDate()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#toDate) method on that Timestamp to convert it, or whatever it is you need to render that on screen.

Comment: I added `toDate()` and now shows the date in the correct format `{{ fechaCreacion.toDate() | date: 'medium' }}`. But I get the following error in console: `TypeError: Can not read property 'toDate' of undefined`

Comment: Well, I don't know why it would both work *and* generate an error.  I don't know Angular, but maybe it's better to use toDate inside component.ts rather than component.html?

Comment: How can I do it in the component.ts? I have tried several options and if it is true the date appears well but the error in the console does not disappear. Any help is appreciated

Comment: `aviso.fechaCreacion.toDate()`?

Comment: `[ts] The property 'toDate' does not exist in the 'Date' type.` error typescript

Comment: I have already solved. I had `fechaCreacion` of type `Date`, I changed it to `any` and the error disappeared. Then it was like your suggestion `aviso.fechaCreacion.toDate()`. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @PacoZevallos I was having the same problem 'toDate' does not exit simply because we defined the field as Date already in our interfaces. The problem is that it is already a date and that is why you can't use the toDate() method on a date type object.

Comment: @richard then you didn't have to use `toDate`? I did not understand.

Answer (score 21):

You have to call **`toDate()`** to convert a Firebase Timestamp to a Javascript Date object before your pipe, for example:

`{{ creationDate.toDate() | date: 'medium' }}`

Comment: That's exactly what I did, and while it's true it works fine but I get the following error: `TypeError: Can not read property 'toDate' of undefined`

Comment: you could use the safe navigation operator: `{{ creationDate?.toDate() | date: 'medium' }}` (note the `?` symbol)

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```html
<ion-col size="4" class="top-center" item-end>
  <ion-label class="second-col second-col-color text-align-right">{{ud.date.toDate() | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</ion-label>
</ion-col>
```

Covert it to toDate like : **date.toDate()**

Answer (score 1):

`Timestamp (seconds = 1528157765, nanoseconds = 878000000)` is not a valid timestamp. It would be the best if backend would use eg ISO time format insteed of `toString()`

Comment: The backend is Firestore, and it's using a Timestamp type object, which needs to be dealt with on its own terms.  What you're quoting here is just the string representation of that object.

Comment: Exactly, its a string representation of timestamp that is sent from backend in uncommon format that will not be autoconverted. Thats the whole point.

Comment: The string representation is *not* being sent from the backend.  The backend is sending a Timestamp object.  The OP is making the mistake of not dealing with it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the date format in the typescript class the use the Datepipe like this

`let s=new Date();
    let x=this.date.transform(s,"yyyy-MM-dd")`