# VS Code shows error for .toDate() function to convert firebase timestamp to Date

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a `date_paid` field stored in a firebase databse as a timestamp:
[image]

In my angular template I display just date as following..

```
<td *ngIf="inc.date_paid">{{ inc?.date_paid.toDate() | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</td>
```

**This works fine**, and output is as expected and no console errors except that VS Code shows linting error. The error shown is:

```
Unknown method 'toDate'ng(0)
```

. How can I do away with this error.

[image]

Or which alternative method I should use?

Comment: Are you sure this is coming from vanilla VS Code? Maybe an extension is causing this error highlighting.

Comment: Yes this is coming from visual studio code

Comment: What is the declared type of inc and of inc.date_paid?

Comment: It is a `Date` in the model...

Comment: Your tip on extensions has led me to an Extension disbling spree and in my early findings it seems Angular Extension Pack is the one causing this red underline...

Comment: There isn't any toDate() method in the type Date: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date. So that's why the compiler complains. The actual, runtime type of date_paid is not Date. It's something else. That's why it works at runtime.

Comment: Maybe it's related to: https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/93 Which only seems to be fixed in Angular 9.0.rc4

Comment: The actual, runtime type of date_paid is not Date. It's something else..... Which type do you think I should use....if in Firebase it is stored as a timestamp?

Comment: This, I guess. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.Timestamp

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

After a deeper research,

I came across a comment in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50956719/6561825)

In my model, just need to change `date_paid: Date` to `date_paid: any`.

The linting error disappeared now I can use `{{inc.date_paid.toDate() ...}}` which gives me the desired output.

Comment: `inc.date_paid` is going to be a Firestore Timestamp type object coming out of Firestore, not a Date.